How to set legend layer invisible in PyQGIS
How I can to set layer (memory layer in my case) invisible in legend, but visible at map?
I saw QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle(node, QgsLegendStyle.Hidden) solution, but I can't find a way to get QgsLegendRenderer of my project.
Or maybe there is some easier solution of that problem?

Would using a private layer be an option? Otherwise maybe check the code of https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/InvisibleLayersAndGroups/
